# any(MyClass.class) that actually matches only classes of the type of the passed class?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, mocking, mockito

I have the following code:

```
verify(javaCompiler, times(1)).writeJavaAndCompile(any(ContractCompilationUnit.class), eq(outputDirectory));
verify(javaCompiler, times(1)).writeJavaAndCompile(any(ParamCompilationUnit.class), eq(outputDirectory));
```

and my code is the following:

```
javaCompiler.writeJavaAndCompile(new ContractCompilationUnit(), outputDirectory);
javaCompiler.writeJavaAndCompile(new ParamCompilationUnit(), outputDirectory);
```

The code is failing, as it seems that the 1st verify sees that there were 2 calls to `javaCompiler.writeJavaAndCompile()`. It is failing to realize that there was only one call of type `ContractCompilationUnit` type.

What's the standard procedure to avoid this behaviour (other than having to write my own matcher)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [documentation](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/Matchers.html#any%28java.lang.Class%29) shows that this is the known behaviour:

> Any kind object, not necessary of the given class. The class argument is provided only to avoid casting.
> Sometimes looks better than anyObject() - especially when explicit casting is required
>
> Alias to anyObject()
>
> This method *don't do any type checks*, it is only there to avoid casting in your code. This might however change (type checks could be added) in a future major release.

It looks like you should use `isA` instead:

```
verify(javaCompiler).writeJavaAndCompile(isA(ContractCompilationUnit.class),
                                         eq(outputDirectory));
```

Comment: Yes, definitely `isA`.  But PLEASE don't write `times(1)` - it doesn't add anything and it makes my skin crawl.

Comment: @DavidWallace: I was merely copying the OP's original code :) Not having used Mockito, I can presumably just remove that call entirely?

Comment: Thank you for doing so, @JonSkeet.  You've just made the world a slightly saner place.